# Merge branches depending on each other

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-merge

sorry for question, which is asked so many times, but I just cant find solution for my problem.

I have a lot of tasks, some of them are depended on others tasks, so lets say, we have:

- task 1: add table (merge required)
- task 2: using table from task 1, add button to add something using form (merge required)
- task 3: using previous solutions, but after adding something into table, you are able to click on it to see details (merge required)

So as you can see, task 1 needs to be merged into master, task 2 is depended on task 1, so you have to include it, also merge is required and task 3 require both task 1 and 2.

And as you know, code review takes a lot of time, so I dont want to just sit and wait, but I want to continue on task 2 while task 1 is reviewing, and then working on task 3 while task 2 is reviewing.

Is there a way how to do it? Im using VS Code with Gitlens extension, also using terminal to push.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mounting branches one of top of the other? That would be the standard way, the only thing to keep in mind is that when you are "updating" you have to be more careful. As an example, task2 branch starts from task1 branch while task1 is still in development. A while later, task1 has received a couple of commits. In order for task2 to get them:

```
git checkout task2
git rebase task1
```

That should be enough to move task2 on top of the new position of task1... but things get much trickier when task1 "moves" (as in, task1 is rebased). In this context you can't just "rebase" because if you tried to do it, git would try to rebase the "previous" revisions from task1 on top of the new position of track1. It might be very simple to assume that if task1 remained the same, then you will get some messages from git saying that the patch has been applied and that you could tell git to skip them.... but the real thing to keep in mind is that, actually, the new task1 branch could be *very* different from the old task1 that you started working from... and given that task1 is not part of the development of task2 (as in, two independent developments), then you would have to rebase task2 *only* to the new position of task1. So, you would have to do:

```
git rebase --onto task1 old-task1-position task2
```

This way you are asking git to rebase onto the *new* position of task1 the branch task2 discarding all previous revisions that were part of the history of old-task1-position.

It's not that hard to work this way, it only requires practice and knowing *what's going on*.

Comment: hmm and how can I solve problem, where I pushed task 1 for code review, then start task 2 which is not a part of task 1, from master (task 1 not included), made some changes, then realized that I need solution from task 1. What Im trying to say is, one of my task was about translations, I pushed them, then started working on another task, different task, but I later realized, that I need translations from task 1, is there a way to solve this? Can rebase help me?

Comment: You can always have fun cherry-picking whatever you need. Say you need to start task2 but taking the second to last revision of task1 as it stands right now. That can be done like this: `git checkout -b task2 master && git cherry-pick task1~1`. Now you start having fun with task2.... after you have 3 revisions committed on task2 you realize that task1 has been merged into master... then you can get on top of the new position of master like this: `git rebase --onto master task2~3 task2` (rebase the last 3 revision of task2 on top of master).... continues

Comment: Sure, rebase can _help_ you.... it can not **save you from yourself**, say. You have to know how to use the tool.

Comment: hmm ok thank you very much, Im still new to git, so a lot of learning is waiting for me :)